Entering Spain from outside the EU with a residence permit
I am an Indian citizen working in Spain. I currently have a valid residence permit from Spain ("permiso de residencia"), but the visa by which I entered Spain has expired. If I travel to India, can I enter Spain again without getting a new visa, as I have a valid residence permit? I am asking as I have a residence permit from Spain, but I am not a permanent resident of Spain. My guess is that I should be allowed to enter, but I am not sure as I don't know how residence permits in Spain work exactly.

A Schengen residence permit serves as a visa replacement and allows you to enter through any Schengen country on your way to Spain. It also allows you to visit other Schengen countries as a Schengen visa does.

Holding a residency permit gives you legal rights to enter EU from any member Schengen states if you travel to India and enter Spain within the valid period of your residency permit you will be allowed to enter without needing to have a visa sticker in your passport

A Schengen residence permit does not allow you enter Ireland (which is an EU country) if your citizenship requires a visa for Ireland.

You did not read my answer fully.

@SaranshSharma, you can enter the whole Schengen zone, not the whole EU. You have to be precise when you answer visa questions.
